# Alternative or github.com/gogo/protobuf/parser package

Tags: go

I'm searching for a package to parse a protobuf file and then found this [1]:

```
github.com/gogo/protobuf/parser
```

However, when I tried to do *go get github.com/gogo/protobuf/parser* there was no such package. Anyone knows another alternative of this package?

[1] https://libraries.io/go/github.com%2Fgogo%2Fprotobuf%2Fparser

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 2):

You are using unofficial and old documentation from Libraries.io.

Use official, up-to-date documentation, and follow the installation intructions.

Protocol Buffers for Go with Gadgets: 
https://github.com/gogo/protobuf

[Getting Started](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf#getting-started)

[Installation](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf#installation)

Answer (score 0):

you can use default protobuf - https://github.com/golang/protobuf if you have errors in your protobuffers it says you after generating

all you need about usage and installation you can read in readme https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/README.md